# How to fix json parsing problems in Angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to send a contactItem (string element) from my `index.html` to my js application using angular.js via `http.post`. 
Every time I try to post the contactItem I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m (or D)
```

at parse.

I tried `JSON.stringify(contactItem)` and `JSON(contactItem);`, but it didn't help.

Hopefully someone can help me figure this out. Thanks.

[image]

index.html

```
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<table style="width:100%">
 <tr ng-repeat="contact in databases.databases">
    <td>{{ contact.name }} <button type="button"ng-click="addContactlist(contact.name)">Click Me</button></td>
    <td>{{ contact.sizeOnDisk }} </td>
    <td>{{ contact.empty }} </td>
  </tr>
  </table> 
</div>

</body>
```

global.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("controller connected");

function refresh(){ 
// create contacklist route 
$http.get('/databases').success(function(response) {
    console.log("recived data requested");
    $scope.databases = response; 
  });
}

// Call refresh to init cantacklist 
refresh(); 


// add Doc to table 
$scope.addContactlist = function(contactItem) {
  alert("Working ");
    $http.post('/collection', JSON.stringify(contactItem)).success(function(response) {
      });
    console.log("posted: "+contactItem);
  };


});// Controller
```

mvc.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path'); //core module 
var databaseUrl = "localhost:27017/DB"; // default env
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
    GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
    Grid = require('mongodb').Grid,
    Code = require('mongodb').Code,
    assert = require('assert');

//configure app
var app = express(); 
var db = new Db('DB', new Server('localhost', 27017));


db.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('database error', err)
}); 

db.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('database connected')
}); 

// store all html files in views 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
// parses recived json input 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// store all js in Scripts folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/scripts'));

// Technology not needed but good practice, especailly when serval people are working on it 
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
}); 

// listen for contactlist get request, aka transfers the contacklist in mongo to client
app.get('/databases', function (req, res) {
    console.log("-- recived GET request --"); 
    db.open(function(err, db) {

      // Use the admin database for the operation
      var adminDb = db.admin();

      // List all the available databases
      adminDb.listDatabases(function(err, dbs) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        assert.ok(dbs.databases.length > 0);
        console.log(dbs);
        res.json(dbs); 
        db.close();
      });
    });
}); 

// listen for contactlist get request, aka transfers the contacklist in mongo to client
app.get('/collection', function (req, res) {
    console.log("-- recived GET request --"); 
    db.open(function(err, db) {
         // Grab a collection without a callback no safe mode
        var col1 = db.collection('DB');
    });
}); 



// Implement a web server to listen to requests 
app.listen(4444, function(){
    console.log('ready on port 4444'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$http.post` need data should be passed in json format like here `contactItem` is nothing only `contact.name` which wouldn't get strigify in any sense. I would suggest you to create `JSON` object before parsing it.

```
$http.post('/collection', JSON.stringify({'contactItem': contactItem})
//$http.post('url', data); //data should be in json format.
```

Also on node.js code that call should be 
app.post
 instead of app.get

Comment: This fixed the parse error. However app.get(), isnt printing to the console. Should i not use stringify() ?

Comment: Yes..try without stringify please

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token D
    at parse. Yeah idk what else to try

Comment: Is the problem the routing ?

Comment: Not sure with nodejs stuff..sorry

Comment: Yeah thanks anyway. Yeah im super sure its the routing

Comment: I think the post call should be app.post instead of app.get

Comment: this parsing is done internally already by `$http`. Have never had to do this with angular when defaults are used. Just pass object as second argument

Comment: http didn’t parse it. @PankajParkar Parkar flobal.js posts the info to the server, and server gets it with a get.  So im pretty sure this is correct